# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^{10} x}{1 +x^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

How one would evaluate the following integral?

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{10}(x)}{1+x^3} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I have tried substitution with no success as well as differentiation under integral sign.
Can anyone help me please. I prefer not to use contour integration.

Comment: $t \equiv {1 \over 1 + x^{3}}$ should lead somehow to the use of the Beta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Caveat.** I wrote  the following answer not having  seen the request
by the OP that he would prefer not to use contour integration. Perhaps
what  follows  can  help  make  the  case  for  and  showcase  contour
integration  for this  integral  which  belongs to  a  class that  has
frequently appeared here at MSE.

Observe  that if  we are  allowed  to use  a CAS  (which would  appear
necessary for this problem) then we may compute

$$Q_n = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^n x}{x^3+1}\; dx
= \int_0^\infty f_n(x) \; dx$$

where

$$f_n(z) = \frac{\log^n z}{z^3+1}$$

by computing all $Q_n$ recursively by integrating $f_{n+1}(z), f_n(z),
\ldots$  and so  on around  a  keyhole contour  with the  slot on  the
positive real axis and the branch cut of the logarithm on that axis as
well, with argument  from $0$ to $2\pi.$ The poles  of $f_n(z)$ are at
$\rho_k =  \exp(\pi i/3 + 2\pi  ik /3)$ with $k=0,1,2.$  We obtain for
the residues

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_k} f_n(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_k} \frac{\log^n z}{z^3+1}
\\ = \left. \frac{\log^n z}{3z^2} \right|_{z=\rho_k}
= \left. z \frac{\log^n z}{3z^3} \right|_{z=\rho_k}
= - \left. \frac{1}{3} z \log^n z \right|_{z=\rho_k}
\\ = - \frac{1}{3} \exp(\pi i/3 + 2\pi ik /3)
(\pi i/3 + 2\pi i k/3)^n = \alpha_{n,k}.$$

We obtain by integrating $f_n(z)$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^n z}{z^3+1} \; dz +
\int_\infty^0 \frac{(2\pi i + \log z)^n}{z^3+1} \; dz
\\ = 2\pi i \sum_k \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_k} f_n(z)
= 2\pi i \sum_k \alpha_{n,k}.$$

This yields

$$ \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n\choose p} (2\pi i)^{n-p}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^p z}{z^3+1} \; dz
= - 2\pi i \sum_k \alpha_{n,k}$$

which is

$$ \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n\choose p} (2\pi i)^{n-p-1} Q_p
= - \sum_k \alpha_{n,k}$$

or

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n} {n+1\choose p} (2\pi i)^{n-p} Q_p
= - \sum_k \alpha_{n+1,k}$$

Therefore to  compute $Q_n$ we use the recurrence

$$Q_n = - \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_k \alpha_{n+1,k}
- \frac{1}{n+1} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n+1\choose p} (2\pi i)^{n-p} Q_p$$

We just need the base case  $Q_0$ which we compute using a pizza slice
resting on the positive real axis and having argument $2\pi/3$ so that
it only contains $\alpha_{0,0}.$ Parameterizing with $z=\exp(2\pi i/3)
t$ we get

$$Q_0 - \exp(2\pi i/3) Q_0 = 2\pi i \alpha_{0,0} $$

which yields

$$Q_0 = - \frac{1}{3} 2\pi i \frac{\exp(\pi i/3)}{1-\exp(2\pi i/3)}
= - \frac{1}{3} 2\pi i \frac{1}{\exp(-\pi i/3)-\exp(\pi i/3)}
\\ = \frac{1}{3} \pi \frac{1}{\sin(\pi/3)} 
= \frac{2}{9}\sqrt{3}\pi.$$

With everything in place we obtain e.g. the sequence up to $n=10$

$$-{\frac {2\,{\pi }^{2}}{27}},{\frac {10\,{\pi }^{3}
\sqrt {3}}{243}},-{\frac {14\,{\pi }^{4}}{243}},{\frac
{34\,{\pi }^{5}\sqrt {3}}{729}},\\-{\frac {806\,{\pi }^{6
}}{6561}},{\frac {910\,{\pi }^{7}\sqrt {3}}{6561}},-{
\frac {10414\,{\pi }^{8}}{19683}},{\frac {415826\,{\pi
}^{9}\sqrt {3}}{531441}},\\-{\frac {685762\,{\pi }^{10}}{
177147}},{\frac {3786350\,{\pi }^{11}\sqrt {3}}{531441}},
\ldots$$

The  Maple code  for this  is extremely  simple, consisting  of  a few
lines.

```
alpha := (n,k) ->
-1/3 * exp(Pi*I/3+2*Pi*I*k/3) * (Pi*I/3 + 2*Pi*I*k/3)^n;

Q :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local res;

    if n = 0 then return 2/9*sqrt(3)*Pi fi;

    res :=
    -1/(n+1)*add(alpha(n+1,k), k=0..2)
    -1/(n+1)*add(binomial(n+1, p)*(2*Pi*I)^(n-p)*Q(p),
                 p=0..n-1);

    simplify(res);
end;

VERIF := n -> int((log(x))^n/(x^3+1), x=0..infinity);
```

Observe  that this  method generalizes  quite nicely.  Suppose we  are
interested in

$$K_n = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^n x}{x^3-2x+4} \; dx.$$

The same  computation goes  through except now  we have  the following
three poles and their logarithms

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|} \hline
\text{pole} & \text{logarithm} \\ \hline
\rho_0  = 1+i
&  \log \rho_0 = \frac{1}{2} \log 2 + \frac{1}{4}i\pi \\ \hline
\rho_1  = 1-i
&  \log \rho_1 = \frac{1}{2} \log 2 + \frac{7}{4}i\pi \\ \hline
\rho_2  = -2
& \log \rho_2 = \log 2 + i\pi.\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The rest is unchanged. We obtain e.g.

$$K_4 = {\frac {357\,{\pi }^{5}}{10240}}-{\frac {31\, \left( \ln 
 \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{5}}{1600}}-{\frac {139\,
 \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{3}{\pi }^{2}}{1920
}} \\ -{\frac {4897\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) {\pi }^{4}}{76800}}+
{\frac {9\, \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{4}\pi 
}{640}}+{\frac {63\, \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) 
^{2}{\pi }^{3}}{1280}}.$$

The Maple code is very similar to the first version.

```
alpha_sum :=
proc(n)
local poles;

    poles :=
    [[1+I, 1/2*log(2) + I*Pi/4],
     [1-I, 1/2*log(2) + 7*I*Pi/4],
     [-2, log(2) + I*Pi]];

    add(residue(1/(x^3-2*x+4), x=p[1])*p[2]^n,
                p in poles);
end;

Q :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local res;

    if n = 0 then
        return
        simplify(int(1/(x^3-2*x+4), x=0..infinity));
    fi;

    res :=
    -1/(n+1)*alpha_sum(n+1)
    -1/(n+1)*add(binomial(n+1, p)*(2*Pi*I)^(n-p)*Q(p),
                 p=0..n-1);

    simplify(res);
end;

VERIF := n -> int((log(x))^n/(x^3-2*x+4), x=0..infinity);
```

Comment: it is excellent

Comment: Marko, I was endeavoring to proceed along precisely this way forward to developing a solution for a similar post.  But, I saw your comment on that post, had a look, and decided I would defer.  +1 for this thorough answer!  -Mark

Comment: Thank you for these kind words. The post where I added the comment just now requires a bit more, asking for an EGF of the values, which I might look at tomorrow, feel free to solve this part if you are interested.

Comment: @Dr.MV The answer to this part is at the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976510/).

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**. One may use the [Euler beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) in the form
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-s}}{1+x^3}dx=\frac13\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{-(s+2)/3}}{1+u}du=\frac{\pi}{3\sin (\pi (s+2)/3)}, \quad -2<s<1,
$$ giving, by differentiating ten times and putting $s=0$,

> $$
> \int_0^\infty\frac{(\log x)^{10}}{1+x^3}dx=\left.\frac{d^{10}}{ds^{10}}\left(\frac{\pi}{3\sin (\pi (s+2)/3)} \right)\right|_{s=0} =\frac{3786350\: \pi ^{11}}{177147 \sqrt{3}}.
> $$

Comment: @OlivierOloa.Sorry I posted wrong problem please see the edit.

Comment: What's t in the yellow blanket?

Comment: @OlivierOloa have you calculated it manually

Comment: @shikharsinghal No.

Comment: I just wanted an another method for it as I think no one will be willing to calculate  it manually.well thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$n\geq 2,m\geq 0$,  integer,

\begin{align}J_n(m)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^m x}{1+x^n}\,dx\end{align}

Observe that,

\begin{align}J_n(m)&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m x}{1+x^n}\,dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^m x}{1+x^n}\,dx\\
\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of integral $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$,

\begin{align}J_n(m)&=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+(-1)^mx^{n-2})\ln^m x}{1+x^n}\,dx\end{align}

Observe that for $x \in [0;1[$,

\begin{align} \frac{1-x}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}+\frac{2x^5}{1-x^6}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^3}\end{align}

thus,

\begin{align}J_3(2m+1)&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2m+1} x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln^{2m+1} x}{1-x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{2x^5\ln^{2m+1} x}{1-x^6}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{x^2\ln^{2m+1} x}{1-x^3}\,dx\\\end{align}

In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
In the third integral perform the change of variable $y=x^6$,
In the fourth integral perform the change of variable $y=x^3$,

\begin{align}J_3(2m+1)&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}+\frac{1}{3\times 6^{2m+1}}-\frac{1}{3^{2m+2}}\right)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2m+1} x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=(2m+1)!\left(\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}-\frac{1}{3\times 6^{2m+1}}+\frac{1}{3^{2m+2}}-1\right)\zeta(2m+2)
\end{align}

Consider,

\begin{align}K_n(m)&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^m(xy)}{(1+x^n)(1+y^n)}\,dx\,dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}J_n(k)J_n(m-k)\\
 \end{align}

On the other hand, perform the change of variable $u=yx$,

\begin{align}K_n(m)&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{y^{n-1}\ln^m(u)}{(u^n+y^n)(1+y^n)}\,du\,dy\\
 \end{align}

perform the change of variable $v=y^n$,

\begin{align}K_n(m)&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^m(u)}{(u^n+v)(1+v)}\,du\,dv\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty \left[\frac{1}{u^n-1}\ln\left(\frac{v+1}{v+u^n}\right)\right]_0^\infty \ln^m(u)\,du\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{m+1}(u)}{u^n-1}\,du\\
 \end{align}

\begin{align}K_3(2m)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2m+1}(u)}{u^3-1}\,du\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+u)\ln^{2m+1}(u)}{u^3-1}\,du\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2m+1}(u)}{u-1}\,du-\int_0^1 \frac{u^2\ln^{2m+1}(u)}{u^3-1}\,du
\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=u^3$,

\begin{align}K_3(2m)&=\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{2m+2}}\right)\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^{2m+1}(u)}{u-1}\,du\\
&=(2m+1)!\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{2m+2}}\right)\zeta(2m+2)
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}J_3(k)J_3(2m-k)=(2m+1)!\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{2m+2}}\right)\zeta(2m+2)
\end{align}

Observe that,

\begin{align}J_3(0)^2=\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{2}}\right)\zeta(2)\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}J_3(0)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{\zeta(2)}\end{align}

If you know that,

\begin{align}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\end{align}

then,

\begin{align}J_3(0)=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}\pi\end{align}

Thus, if $m>0$,

\begin{align}J_3(2m)=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4\pi}\left((2m+1)!\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{2m+2}}\right)\zeta(2m+2)-\sum_{k=1}^{2m-1}\binom{2m}{k}J_3(k)J_3(2m-k)\right)
\end{align}

If you know $\zeta(2),...,\zeta(2m+2)$ then you can compute $J_3(2m)$

Here is code for GP PARI:

```
Integrat(n)={
if(n>50,return(0));
Z=vector(52);
J=vector(50);
P=Pi;
R=sqrt(3);
for(k=1,n+1,L=lindep([Pi^(2*k),zeta(2*k)]);Z[2*k]=-L[1]/L[2]*P^(2*k));
for(k=0,n-1,J[2*k+1]=(2*k+1)!*(1/2^(2*k+1)-1/(3*6^(2*k+1))+1/3^(2*k+2)-1)*Z[2*k+2]);
for(k=1,n,J[2*k]=3*R/(4*P)*((2*k+1)!*(1-1/3^(2*k+2))*Z[2*k+2]-sum(s=1,2*k-1,binomial(2*k,s)*J[s]*J[2*k-s])));
L=lindep([J[2*n],Pi^(2*n+1)*sqrt(3)]);
print("intnum(x=0,[+1],log(x)^",2*n,"/(1+x^3))=",-L[2]/L[1],"*sqrt(3)Pi^",2*n+1);
}
```

NB:

Code assumes that:

\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{2n}x}{1+x^3}\,dx=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\sqrt{3}\pi^{2n+1}\end{align} $a_n,b_n$ natural integers.