# Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\,dx$ with residue theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}\,dx$$

using the Residue Theorem. The contour I want to use is almost the upper half circle of radius $R$, but going around $0$ following a half-circle of radius $\epsilon$, and using the branch cut at $3\pi/2$. The picture is below. Let's call the left segment $L_1$ and the right one $L_2$.

[image: Described contour]

I can show that $\int_{C_R}\frac{\log z}{z^2+4} = 0.$ I don't know what to do about $\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{\log z}{z^2+4}$. I've got

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{C_\epsilon}\frac{\log z}{z^2+4}\,dz\right| &=\left|-\int_{-C_\epsilon}\frac{\log z}{z^2+4}\,dz\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{0}^\pi\frac{\log(\epsilon e^{it})}{\epsilon^2e^{2it}+4}\cdot i\epsilon e^{it}\,dt\right|\\
&\le\int_{0}^\pi\left|\frac{\log(\epsilon e^{it})}{\epsilon^2e^{2it}+4}\cdot i\epsilon e^{it}\right|\,dt\\
&\le\int_{0}^\pi\left|\frac{\log(\epsilon e^{it})}{\epsilon^2e^{2it}+4}\cdot i\epsilon e^{it}\right|\,dt\\
&\le\int_{0}^\pi\left|\frac{\log(\epsilon e^{it})}{4}\cdot i\epsilon e^{it}\right|\,dt\\
&=\int_{0}^\pi\frac{\left|\ln \epsilon + it\right|}{4}\cdot \epsilon\,dt
\end{align}
$$

**Edit**
<s>But this goes to $\infty$ as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to get a better estimate that goes to $0$? I also don't understand how the branch cut plays a role, as long as we picked something that didn't intersect the contour.</s>

(I've changed the calculation to reflect the comment.) I see that this goes to $0$. Using the residue theorem to calculate the integral over the whole contour, I get

$$
\begin{align}
2\pi i\text{Res}_{2i} \frac{\log z}{z^2+4} &=\left. 2\pi i\frac{log z}{2z}\right|_{z=2i}\\
&=2\pi i\cdot\frac{log(2i)}{4i}\\
&=\frac{ln 2 + i\frac{\pi}{2}}{4i}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\ln 2 + i\frac{\pi}{2}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Since

$$\int_{L_1} f(z) + \int_{L_2} f(z) \to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2+4}, $$
I almost have what I want. But what about that $i\pi/2$?

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{1}{4}\pi \log(2)$$

Comment: for small $\epsilon$ the denonminator is $\sim 4$ not $\sim\epsilon^2$

Comment: furthermore to calculate this integral it is much easier to exploit the symmetry of the integrand under the rational fractional transformation $x\rightarrow 1/x$

Comment: What did you use for drawing the contour ?

Comment: @Dr. MV
Since $\log$ is so special the argument still goes through:
$$2I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-\log(x)}{1+4x^2}=\\\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)+\log(2)}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-\log(x)+\log(2)}{x^2+1}=\\\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(2)}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$

Comment: @Dr.MV not only in your case ;-)

Comment: @tire (+1) Nice one.

Comment: There are some relevant readings at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854854/).

Answer (score 2):

It is more useful the [keyhole contour](https://www.google.it/search?hl=it&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=662&q=keyhole+contour&oq=keyhole+con&gs_l=img.3.0.0i30k1j0i8i30k1.96.2391.0.3366.11.11.0.0.0.0.181.1295.0j9.9.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..2.9.1290...0j0i10k1.PoivChLol4Y#imgrc=b9MQhIBq0M8u8M:). Consider the function $$f\left(z\right)=\frac{\log^{2}\left(z\right)}{z^{2}+4}$$ and the branch of the logarithm corresponding to $-\pi<\arg\left(z\right)\leq\pi.$ Take the classic keyhole contour $\gamma$. It is not difficult to prove that the integrals over the circumferences vanish so by the residue theorem $$2\pi i\left(\underset{z=2i}{\textrm{Res}}f\left(z\right)+\underset{z=-2i}{\textrm{Res}}f\left(z\right)\right)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{2}\left(-x+i\epsilon\right)}{\left(x-i\epsilon\right)^{2}+4}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{2}\left(-x-i\epsilon\right)}{\left(x+i\epsilon\right)^{2}+4}dx\right)$$ $$=4\pi i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{x^{2}+4}dx.$$ Hence $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{x^{2}+4}dx=\color{red}{\frac{\pi\log\left(2\right)}{4}}.$$

Comment: Marco, it's good to see you're still here!  (+1) and this is the standard way to proceed.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you Mark!

Comment: But this evaluates two residues and the logarithm is squared. The OP approach seems easier.

Answer (score 2):

After the edit, you should have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx+\int_\epsilon^R\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx&=\int_\epsilon^R\frac{\log(-x)}{x^2+4}\,dx+\int_\epsilon^R\frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx\\\\
&=\color{blue}{2\int_\epsilon^R \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx}+\color{red}{i\pi\int_\epsilon^R \frac{1}{x^2+4}\,dx}\tag 1\\\\
\oint_C\frac{\log(z)}{z^2+4}\,dz&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\log(z)}{z^2+4}, z=i2\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \frac{\log(2i)}{4i}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac\pi2\log(2)}+\color{red}{i\frac{\pi^2}{4}}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$, equating real and imaginary parts of $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+4}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve this answer too. As always, I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful, I am happy to delete it. -Mark