# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+6x+10}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+6x+10}dx$$

The given answer is $0.370429$. Is there any method to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is closed form for the antiderivative but it involves special functions (polylogarithms). For the integral, the result seems to be $\frac 12 \log(10)\tan^{-1}(\frac 13)$

Comment: What method should I use?

Comment: What is your background? Do you like the words "complex analysis", "residue", "contour integral"?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Numerical evidence shows the formula to be correct, but I think one can obtain it by integrating $\ln^2z/(z^2-6z+10)$ along the "boundary" of the complex plane cut along the negative real axis, without any polylogarithms.

Comment: @ProfessorVector. You are very correct and this is very interesting. Why don't you put an answer ? It will be very instructive for every one. Cheers and thanks for providing this idea.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I'm sorry, but no, I won't do that, not after the amazing answer by Jack. He's got the one ring to rule them all (all the integrals), obviously. ;-) It's quite some calculation, btw **very** similar to xpaul's answer, an answer I like a lot, too.

Comment: There is an algorithm for these which was posted at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854854/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually Complex Analysis (or the dilogarithm machinery) is not strictly needed to solve the given integral, it is enough to exploit a substitution and a *hidden symmetry*.

$$\mathfrak{I}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2+6x+10}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto z\sqrt{10}}{=}\sqrt{10}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\log(10)+\log z}{10z^2+6\sqrt{10}\, z+10}\,dz$$
but by enforcing the substitution $z\mapsto\frac{1}{z}$ we also have 
$$\mathfrak{I}=\sqrt{10}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\log(10)\color{red}{-}\log z}{10z^2+6\sqrt{10}\,z+10}\,dz$$
from which it follows that
$$ 2\mathfrak{I} = \sqrt{10}\log(10)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{10z^2+6\sqrt{10}\,z+10} $$
and the problem boils down to the evaluation of an elementary integral.

Comment: Wow.${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: That is a smart solution.

Comment: No doubt ! This is more than beautiful !

Comment: Nice solution. Nice trick to transform the polynomial into a palindromic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Note 
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x+1}dx=-\frac{\pi}{\sin(a\pi)}$$
and hence
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x+b}dx=-\frac{b^a\pi}{\sin(a\pi)}. $$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+6x+10}dx\\
&=&\lim_{a\to0}\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{x^2+6x+10}dx\\
&=&\lim_{a\to0}\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{(x+3)^2+1}dx\\
&=&\lim_{a\to0}\frac{i}{2}\frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^\infty\left(\frac{x^a}{x+3+i}-\frac{x^a}{x+3-i}\right)dx\\
&=&\lim_{a\to0}\frac{i}{2}\frac{d}{da}\bigg[-\frac{(3+i)^a}{\sin(a\pi)}+\frac{(3-i)^a}{\sin(a\pi)}\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{a\to0}\frac{i}{2}\frac{d}{da}\frac{(3-i)^a-(3+i)^a}{\sin(a\pi)}\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{a\to0}\frac{i}{2}\frac{[(3-i)^a \ln (3-i)-(3+i)^a \ln (3+i)]\sin(a\pi)-[(3-i)^a-(3+i)^a]\cos(a\pi)}{\sin^2(a\pi)}\\
&=&\frac{i}{4}[\ln^2(3-i)-\ln^2(3+i)]\\
&=&\frac{i}{4}\ln[(3-i)(3+i)]\ln[(3-i)/(3+i)]\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\ln10\arctan(\frac13).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I guess the first integral should be $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x+1}dx=-\frac{\pi}{\sin(a\pi)}.$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector, yes, you are right. I changed.

Comment: Ok. You left out the justifications for interchanging integral and differentiation/limits, but since those justifications are fairly obvious, that was the right decision: better to emphasize the main ideas than to drown them in technicalities.