# Integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+nx+n^2}dx=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was working on some integrals, and I proved the following really beautiful identity:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+nx+n^2}dx=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

I found it by solving $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{ax^2+bx+c}dx$, and then differentiating my result with respect to $k$ and evaluating at $k=1$. When I saw that it yielded a nice formula for the above integral, I was surprised, which is why I posted this question.

But my proof is very long and messy, and since the result is so elegant, I was wondering if there was a simple and elegant proof of this identity.

Comment: What is the idea of your proof?

Comment: Can you tell in short terms what your proof consisted of?  There is quite a short proof for it and I can't see a long one.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2473132/515527 too.

Comment: I had found $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{ax^2+bx+c}dx$, for a general $a,b,c$, and then I plugged in $a=1$, $b=n$ and $c=n^2$ to get this equation, which I know is not at all optimal.

Comment: Well, how did you find that general integral in a long and messy way?

Comment: I found it by solving $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{ax^2+bx+c}dx$, and then differentiating my result with respect to $k$ and evaluating at $k=1$.

Comment: Ouch no, that is definitely not a nice way to go about it. Dx

Comment: Yeah, my original goal was to solve $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{ax^2+bx+c}dx$, and then when I saw that it yielded such a since formula for $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2+nx+n^2}dx$, I was surprised which is why I posted this question.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it's definetly messy to approach it that way.

Comment: Since someone wants to delete this topic, I'll open it.

Answer (score 5):

Let $I(n)$ be the integral in question. Then, using the substitution
$x=ny$, we get
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(nx)}{n(x^2+x+1)}\,dx=I(1)+
\frac{\ln n}n\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{y^2+y+1}.$$
That latter integral can be done by a arctangent substitution. But
using the substitution $y=1/x$ gives $I(1)=-I(1)$ so that $I(1)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Call your integral $I$. With $x\mapsto\frac{n^2}{x}$, $I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(n/x)dx}{x^2+nx+n^2}$. Averaging, $I=\frac12\ln n\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+nx+n^2}$.