# $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve
$$
\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx=0.
$$
The problem is that when I use the curve[image]

I have that
\begin{align*}
0
&=\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\log^3 z}{z^2+1}\\
&=\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{\log^3 z}{z^2+1}
+\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{\log^3 z}{z^2+1}
+\int_{r}^R\frac{\log^3x}{x^2+1}
+\int_{-R}^{-r}\frac{(\log|x|+i\pi)^3}{x^2+1}
\end{align*}
where $\log z$ is the log without negative pure complex numbers. Also ($\rho=R$ or $\rho=r$)
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma_\rho}\frac{\log^3z}{z^2+1}
&=\int_0^\pi\frac{(\log\rho+i\theta)^3}{\rho^2e^{2i\theta}+1}i\rho e^{i\theta}\,d\theta
=\int_0^\pi\frac{\log^3\rho-i\theta^3+3i\theta\log^2\rho-3i\theta^2\log\rho}{\rho^2e^{2i\theta}+1}i\rho e^{i\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^\pi\frac{\log^3\rho}{\rho^2e^{2i\theta}+1}i\rho e^{i\theta}\,d\theta
-i\int_0^\pi\frac{\theta^3}{\rho^2e^{2i\theta}+1}i\rho e^{i\theta}\,d\theta
+3i\int_0^\pi\frac{\theta\log^2\rho}{\rho^2e^{2i\theta}+1}i\rho e^{i\theta}\,d\theta
-3i\int_0^\pi\frac{\theta^2\log\rho}{\rho^2e^{2i\theta}+1}i\rho e^{i\theta}\,d\theta
\end{align*}
And
\begin{align*}
\int_{-R}^{-r}\frac{(\log|x|+i\pi)^3}{x^2+1}
=\int_{r}^{R}\frac{(\log|x|+i\pi)^3}{x^2+1}
=\int_{r}^{R}\frac{\log^3x-i\pi^3+3i\pi\log^2x-3i\pi^2\log x}{x^2+1}
\end{align*}
But I'm uncertain if this is the way, cause is huge and I don't know how to lead with integration of $\frac{\log^2x}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: If you don't have to use complex analysis, then you can just observe that the substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$ shows $I = -I$.

Comment: for god sake @DanielSchepler, bless for you

Comment: In the last display equation, you are missing the differentials $dx$, and in the last expression the factor $i$ in the term $-3 i \pi^2 \log x$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: If on the other hand you'd wanted $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2xdx}{x^2+1}$, which doesn't vanish, a keyhole contour might be easier than a semicircular one, although counterintuitively you'd want to integrate $\frac{\log^3z}{z^2+1}$ around it, because the calculation gets a $\ln^2z$ term from expanding $\ln^3z-(\ln z+2i\pi)^3$.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate inasmuch as it includes the even exponent case, but this post is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010205/how-to-solve-int-0-infty-frac-lognx1x2dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any positive, odd integer $k$, the substitution $$x = \frac{1}{u}$$ gives
$$I := \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^k x}{1 + x^2} = - \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^k u}{1 + u^2} = -I .$$

**Remark** For even $k$, the integrand is nonnegative everywhere and positive in some places (in fact, everywhere except $x = 1$), so the integral has positive value.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Travis Willse gave the answer for odd velues of $k$, for the beauty of it
$$I := \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^{2k}( x)}{1 + x^2}\,dx =2^{-4 n}\, n\,\Gamma (2 n)\, \left(\zeta \left(2 n+1,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2 n+1,\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)  $$

$$\zeta \left(2 n+1,\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2 n+1,\frac{3}{4}\right)=2 \pi ^{2 n+1}\,\frac {a_n}{b_n}$$ where the $b_n$ form sequence $A360966$ in $OEIS$ (with a shift of $1$) and the $a_n$ form the (unknown ?) sequence
$$\{1,5,122,277,101042,1081106,797443924,3878302429,4809759350882\}$$

Even the antiderivatives are not too complicated if you enjoy polylogarithms of complex areguments (coming from $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$ followed by partial fraction decomposition).